# Variables not persisting after button click

Tags: java, javafx

I have a program that takes in 2 player names from the welcome screen, and then it is supposed to use them in the Dice Game, however it seems like they do not persist.

When I run the program I get an output like this

```
after welcome button click player1 = 4
after welcome button click player2 = 3
player1 = null
player2 = null
```

I would like to be something like

```
after welcome button click player1 = 4
after welcome button click player2 = 3
player1 = 4
player2 = 3
```

Here is the relevant code

```
Game.java
package DiceGame;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Game extends Application {


    Parent root, welcomeScreen;
    Stage app = new Stage();
    Stage welcome = new Stage();

    Player player1 = new Player();
    Player player2 = new Player();
    private boolean player1Turn = true;


    @FXML
    private TextField player1Name;

    @FXML
    private TextField player2Name;

    @FXML
    private Button closeButton;

    @FXML
    private Button rollButton;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // Load game board
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Game.fxml"));
        // Load the welcome screen
        welcomeScreen = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("WelcomeScreen.fxml"));

        // Set the game board on the window
        app.setScene(new Scene(root, 742, 338));
        app.show();
        // Set the welcome screen to the window, display above the game board
        welcome.setScene(new Scene(welcomeScreen, 600, 400));
        welcome.show();


    }

    private Player getPlayer1() {
        return this.player1;
    }

    private Player getPlayer2() {
        return this.player2;
    }

    @FXML
    private void closeWelcomeScreen() {
        // Get the stage that the button is attached to it
        this.player1.setName(player1Name.getText());
        this.player2.setName(player2Name.getText());
        System.out.println("after welcome button click player1 = " + player1.getName());
        System.out.println("after welcome button click player2 = " + player2.getName());
        Stage stage = (Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow();
        // Close the welcome screen
        stage.hide();
    }

    @FXML
    private void doRoll() {
      // Perform turn
      // Update text for button
        System.out.println("player1 = " + player1.getName());
        System.out.println("player2 = " + player2.getName());

    }
}
```

WelcomeScreen.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="DiceGame.Game">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="201.0" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="244.0" text="Dice Game">
         <font>
            <Font size="41.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextArea layoutX="1.0" layoutY="64.0" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="600.0" text="Welcome to my dice game!&#10;&#10;The rules are simple&#10;&#10;• You will play a computer&#10;• You will take turns rolling dice, until one, or both, players score over 21 points&#10;• The points are as follows&#10;    a) If a pair is rolled, the sum of the pair will be added to the score&#10;    b) If all 3 dice have the same values, 18 will be added to the score&#10;    c) Otherwise 1 point will be added tot he score &#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;" />
      <TextField fx:id="player1Name" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="325.0" prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="75.0" />
      <Label layoutX="50.0" layoutY="325.0" text="Player 1 Name: ">
         <padding>
            <Insets top="3.0" />
         </padding>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="275.0" layoutY="325.0" text="Player 2 Name: ">
         <padding>
            <Insets top="3.0" />
         </padding>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="player2Name" layoutX="375.0" layoutY="325.0" prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="75.0" />
      <Button fx:id="closeButton" layoutX="278.0" layoutY="361.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeWelcomeScreen" text="Close" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Game.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="DiceGame.Game">
   <top>
      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="player1ScoreLabel" text="Player Score:  0">
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="15.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding></Label>
            <Label fx:id="player2ScoreLabel" text="Computer Score:  0">
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding></Label>
            <Label fx:id="leadLabel" text="Both players tied">
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </top>
   <bottom>
      <Button fx:id="rollButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doRoll" text="Click for your turn" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
   <center>

   </center>
   <center>
      <GridPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="firstDie" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@side_1.png" />
               </image>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="45.0" />
               </GridPane.margin></ImageView>
            <ImageView fx:id="secondDie" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@side_1.png" />
               </image>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="45.0" />
               </GridPane.margin></ImageView>
            <ImageView fx:id="thirdDie" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@side_1.png" />
               </image>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="45.0" />
               </GridPane.margin></ImageView>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

How can I get the desired outcome?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is that each fxml will have its dedicated controller instance (even if you use the same class). So you are setting the details in WelcomeScreen controller instance and expecting to get them in Game controller instance.

Firstly I would recommend to have dedicated controller classes for each fxml. Also it is best practise to NOT use Application class as controller class. In your case, you can save the players name in Application class and can access them from different controllers.

Another quick weird way is to declare your players as static ;) (Definitely not recommended)